# Whitelist cloud scheduler IP for access to protected HTTP endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

We use IP whitelisting to gate access to an Nginx Ingress for some administrative services. We have a need for using a Cloud Scheduler call to this endpoint to kick off some background processes. Is it possible to whitelist calls from a specific range from Cloud Functions?

Thanks!